# how to select and change onclick attribute with jquery?

Tags: jquery

with below code i can select all a href's value then change them;

```
$("a").each(function(){
 if (this.hostname == location.hostname){
     var url = this.href;
     var qs = $.jqURL.get('qs');
     if(url.indexOf('qs=') == -1 && (qs!= undefined && qs!= '')){
        if (url.indexOf('?')>0){
            $(this).attr('href', url + '&qs='+ qs);

        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr('href', url + '?qs='+ qs);

        }
    }
 }
})
```

i want to apply onclick attribute like above code too.

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='http://www.domain.com'" style="cursor:pointer">Test</div>
```

thank you very much all, already now...

Regards,
Kerbooo

Comment: `.filter()` needs to return `true` to reduce the set of matched elements.

Comment: like this, it works without giving error

Comment: @Kerberos - You should use `.each()` instead of `.filter()` for what you're doing, or even `.attr('href', function(i, href) {});`.

Comment: I don't understand your original question.  Are you saying you want to add an 'onclick' to every div?

Comment: OK, i fixed "filter" with "each", thank you.

Comment: user384915, i want to change onclick's href value like i made for a href when html loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
attr_val = $("div").attr("onclick");

attr_val.split("=")[1];
```